# Trouble parsing XML in logstash

Tags: elmah, logstash

Our applications are unstable and generate 1000's of elmah error log files. We are trying to see which areas of the applications are error prone and unstable. We have decided to use ElasticSearch, LogStash, Kibana to search through these logs and generate trends. I am trying to configure logstash for this scenario. I am getting the "Something is wrong with your configuration." error when running the "logstash agent -f logstash-simple2.conf" command. What could I be doing wrong? Any pointers are appreciated.

**logstash-simple2.conf:**

```
input {
  stdin {
    type => "stdin-type"
  }

  file {
     type => "file"
     pattern => ["Z:/PROD/availability2/2014-04-15/00/**/*.xml"]
    }
}

output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}
```

**Input file:**

**Actual Error:**

```
?[33mUsing milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}?[0m?[31mUnknown setting 'pattern' for file {:level=>:error}?[0m
Error: Something is wrong with your configuration.You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose to restart a running system.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You file input configuration is wrong, use **Path** instead of Pattern

```
input {
  stdin {
    type => "stdin-type"
  }

  file {
     type => "file"
     path => "Z:/PROD/availability2/2014-04-15/00/**/*.xml"
    }
}

output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}
```